# Как изменить цвет текста если за текстом появился чёрный слайд?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Есть слайдер и поверх него идёт текст в `position: absolute`. Как сделать, чтобы этот текст менял цвет с чёрного на белый, если на слайдере чёрный слайд?

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://u1351602.isp.regruhosting.ru/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/slider-pro.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://u1351602.isp.regruhosting.ru/catalog/view/javascript/slider-pro.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="text">
    <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-pro" id="my-slider">
    <div class="sp-slides">
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/86WPTg8/yellow-slide.png">
      </div>
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Jn9GPxN/green-slide.png">
      </div>
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/sm9B6cw/black-slide.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $( '#my-slider' ).sliderPro({
            width:433,
            height: 246,
            arrows: true,
            fade: true,
            buttons: true,
            waitForLayers: false,
            loop: true,
            smallSize: 500,
            mediumSize: 1000,
            largeSize: 3000,
            autoplay: true,
            autoScaleLayers: true,
            autoplayDelay: 4500,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Вроде обычно дают полу прозрачный фон для блока с текстом

Comment: С помощью JS проверить цвет фона, вычислить, темный он или светлый (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043187/how-to-check-if-hex-color-is-too-black), и в зависимости от этого изменить цвет текста

Answer (score 2):

Можно попытаться использовать комбинацию фильтров и режима наложения:

```css
.content { position: relative; }

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 10px; z-index: 1;
  filter: grayscale(1) invert(1) contrast(10);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://u1351602.isp.regruhosting.ru/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/slider-pro.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://u1351602.isp.regruhosting.ru/catalog/view/javascript/slider-pro.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="text">
    <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-pro" id="my-slider">
    <div class="sp-slides">
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/367/267">
      </div>
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1022/367/267">
      </div>
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/417/367/267">
      </div>
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/232/367/267">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $( '#my-slider' ).sliderPro({
            width:433,
            height: 246,
            arrows: true,
            fade: true,
            buttons: true,
            waitForLayers: false,
            loop: true,
            smallSize: 500,
            mediumSize: 1000,
            largeSize: 3000,
            autoplay: true,
            autoScaleLayers: true,
            autoplayDelay: 4500,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, но не нравится, что текст переливается разными цветами. Можно сделать чтобы текст был только либо белый, либо чёрный?

Comment: @DenKuzmin: может и можно. Вопрос в том, что делать если фон неоднородный - например, шахматный чёрно-белый? Тогда половины текста не будет видно.